# How to do MySQL Join and use PHP to get the values

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, entity-attribute-value

I am trying to write a mysql query to pull data in this format:

```
<table>
    <caption>table title and/or explanatory text</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Field Name 1</th>
            <th>Field Name 2</th>
            <th>Field Name 3</th>
            <th>Field Name 4</th>
            <th>Field Name 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        echo "<tr>
                <td>" .$row{'user_id'}. "</td>
                <td>" .$row{'first_name'}. "</td>
                <td>" .$row{'last_name'}. "</td>
                <td>" .$row{'field_name_1'}. "</td>
                <td>" .$row{'field_name_2'}. "</td>
                <td>" .$row{'field_name_3'}. "</td>
                <td>" .$row{'field_name_4'}. "</td>
                <td>" .$row{'field_name_5'}. "</td>
            </tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The tables in the database are formatted like the following.

Table: user_data

```
user_id      |     first_name     |    last_name     |
------------------------------------------------------
1            |     Jeff           |    Smith         |
------------------------------------------------------
2            |     Bob            |    Smith         |
------------------------------------------------------
3            |     Steve          |    Smith         |
------------------------------------------------------
4            |     Mary           |    Smith         |
------------------------------------------------------
5            |     Anna           |    Smith         |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Table: custom_fields

```
custom_field_id   |    name         |
-------------------------------------
3                 |    field name   |
-------------------------------------
5                 |    field name   |
-------------------------------------
7                 |    field name   |
-------------------------------------
9                 |    field name   |
-------------------------------------
11                |    field name   |
-------------------------------------
```

Table: custom_field_data

```
user_id      |     custom_field_id    |    value     |
------------------------------------------------------
1            |     3                  |    XXXX      |
------------------------------------------------------
1            |     5                  |    BBBB      |
------------------------------------------------------
1            |     7                  |    CCCC      |
------------------------------------------------------
1            |     9                  |    ZZZZ      |
------------------------------------------------------
1            |     11                 |    YYYY      |
------------------------------------------------------
2            |     3                  |    XXXX      |
------------------------------------------------------
2            |     5                  |    BBBB      |
------------------------------------------------------
2            |     7                  |    CCCC      |
------------------------------------------------------
2            |     9                  |    ZZZZ      |
------------------------------------------------------
3            |     3                  |    XXXX      |
------------------------------------------------------
3            |     5                  |    BBBB      |
------------------------------------------------------
3            |     9                  |    ZZZZ      |
------------------------------------------------------
3            |     11                 |    YYYY      |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I am looking for the best solution for querying the data and then printing it to the screen using PHP or AJAX. Is this possible? Would it be better to use json?
And a sample query would be great.

FYI: In the long run all the data being extracted will need to be filtered on the screen. Thanks for the help.

My desired output would be

```
user_id      |     first_name     |    last_name     |  custom_field_3  |   custom_field_5  |   custom_field_7  |   custom_field_9  |   custom_field_11     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            |     Jeff           |    Smith         |  XXXX            |   BBBB            |   CCCC            |   ZZZZ            |   YYYY                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2            |     Bob            |    Smith         |  XXXX            |   BBBB            |   CCCC            |   ZZZZ            |   YYYY                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3            |     Steve          |    Smith         |  XXXX            |   BBBB            |   CCCC            |   ZZZZ            |   YYYY                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4            |     Mary           |    Smith         |  XXXX            |   BBBB            |   CCCC            |   ZZZZ            |   YYYY                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5            |     Anna           |    Smith         |  XXXX            |   BBBB            |   CCCC            |   ZZZZ            |   YYYY                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How does `user_id` relate to `custom_field`? `value` is `name` from `custom_fields`? Here's the join doc, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html. Should be do-able not sure how data relates though..

Comment: The relation is like `user_data.user_id -> custom_field_data.user_id -> custom_fields.name` ... make sense?

Comment: I misread question at first, thought the third table was a view you wanted. I think this might be what you are after `select * from user_data as ud
join 
custom_field_data as cfd
on cfd.user_id = ud.user_id
join 
custom_fields as cf
on cf.custom_field_id = cfd.custom_field_id`

Comment: @chris85 - I managed to edit your query to get exactly what I needed for the data part. The problem now, is that it is printing a row for every custom field ... How do I loop through and produce the HTML above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `group_concat` function, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat, with my previous query to get a single record per user...

If you had a SQLfiddle I could test this out but as is I don't have any data to test with...

```
select ud.firstname, ud.lastname, group_concat(cf.name) 
from user_data as ud 
join custom_field_data as cfd 
on cfd.user_id = ud.user_id 
join custom_fields as cf 
on cf.custom_field_id = cfd.custom_field_id
```

I tested this on 3 tables I have with a similar setup so I think it should work; names may need to be tweaked.

Update:

```
select ud.firstname, ud.lastname, group_concat(cf.name) 
from user_data as ud 
join custom_field_data as cfd 
on cfd.user_id = ud.user_id 
join custom_fields as cf 
on cf.custom_field_id = cfd.custom_field_id
group by ud.user_id
```

Comment: Hey @chris85, I think I am getting close. Now I am only getting the first row to output. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1e5e/6

Comment: Add in a `group by ud.userid` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1e5e/15. I was testing with only 1 record so didn't encounter that previously.

Comment: Ok @chris85 - I got it working here, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88d80/3 - Now i need to know how to get each value in PHP to print the table data.

Comment: Use the same fetching and echo you currently use. Use aliases to have the same column names as before.

Comment: So in the array that is output it looks like this, http://pastebin.com/hdRWE77E ... I am not sure how to loop through the grouped fields as they are combined? Like "27Noe" where 27 is the cf id and Noe is the value ... any help?

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you currently have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86568/discussion-between-chris85-and-matthew-woodard).

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with simple join of your `custom_field_data` to `user_data` table where values and field names are hardcoded:

```
SELECT 
 u.*,
 f1.value as "<Field 1 Name>",
 ...
 f2.value as "<Field N Name>"
FROM 
 user_data u LEFT JOIN 
 custom_field_data f1 ON u.user_id = f1.user_id AND f1.custom_field_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN
 custom_field_data f ON u.user_id = fn.user_id AND fn.custom_field_id = <N>
```

Now, if you want to extract data without hardcoding, you will need to build your SQL dynamically based on data in `custom_fields` table:

```
SELECT * FROM custom_fields;
```

If some of your custom fields are never used in relation to users you would want to limit the number of custom fields like this:

```
SELECT * FROM custom_fields f
WHERE EXISTS 
       (SELECT * FROM custom_field_data 
        WHERE f.custom_field_id = custom_field_id)
```

Finally, to build required SQL in PHP you need these string sections:

```
// Begin SELECT clause (static):
$sql = "SELECT u.*,"

// Add all fields that you selected form the custom_fields:
foreach ($result as $row) { // Don't forget to handle commas
  $sql = $sql + <expression that gets codes and name>
}

// Start FROM clause (static):
$sql = $sql + " FROM user_data u "


// Join to custom_field_data:
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $sql = $sql + " LEFT JOIN custom_field_data <alias expression> ON ..
}
```

In the end you should get a string with SQL, that will join users to `custom_field_data` for each available custom field.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible o pull the data with `$.ajax()` and `PHP`.  Create a file `data.php` we are going to load this file with `ajax`. In your `data.php` file write this code.

```
$query = mysqli_query("select * from custom_field_data 
         inner join 
         user_data on user_data.user_id = custom_field_data.user_id
         inner join 
         custom_fields on custom_field_data.custom_field_id = custom_fields.custom_field_id");
<table>
<caption>table title and/or explanatory text</caption>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Field Name 1</th>
        <th>Field Name 2</th>
        <th>Field Name 3</th>
        <th>Field Name 4</th>
        <th>Field Name 5</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <?php 

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo "<tr>
            <td>" .$row{'user_id'}. "</td>
            <td>" .$row{'first_name'}. "</td>
            <td>" .$row{'last_name'}. "</td>
            <td>" .$row{'field_name_1'}. "</td>
            <td>" .$row{'field_name_2'}. "</td>
            <td>" .$row{'field_name_3'}. "</td>
            <td>" .$row{'field_name_4'}. "</td>
            <td>" .$row{'field_name_5'}. "</td>
        </tr>";
    }
?>
</tbody>
```

In your main page use a `button` to load the data.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#load-data').click(function(){
        $.post('data.php', function(data){
            $('#results').html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

[example on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14dfd/13/0)

Answer (score -2):

The best way in my opinion is to use join because it will reduce the size of data transferred between DB and PHP

You can use JSON as it is light weight.

You can keep the things hidden in hidden field and use that for further filtering in client side completely

update --

For Sql server I would have written a query like this

```
select 
  t1.user_name,
  t1.first_name,
  t1.last_name,
  (select name from custom_fields 
   where custom_field_id= t2.custom_field_id) 
from
 user_data t1 left join
 custom_field_data t2 on t1.user_id=t2.userid
```

Change this according to my-sql

Comment: Thank you Manju, I am looking for a sample query for something like this ... any ideas?

Comment: This will not produce expected results

Comment: I have written the query in relation with sql-server but not in mysql

Comment: The query has written by keeping in mind about the logic...Anyhow we can convert the query to be more effecient ...But it play by logic

Comment: I think you need to expand your answer, as right now I don't see how results of your query will match the task in question.